# String Date in Named query generate ClassCastException

Tags: java, mysql, date, datetime, classcastexception

I am trying to create a named query for all the stringified arguments. This was how my stringified method was:

```
    public Collection<Companypermcache> findExpiredPerms() {
        String date = DateUtils.getSQLDate(DateUtils.getToday());
        StringBuffer qbe = new StringBuffer("select cpc from Companypermcache cpc");
        qbe.append(" where cpc.expire < '"+date+"'");
        return super.findByQuery(qbe.toString());
    }
```

I convert this to named query like below

```
        String date = DateUtils.getSQLDate(DateUtils.getToday());
        StringBuffer qbe = new StringBuffer("select cpc from Companypermcache cpc");
        qbe.append(" where cpc.expire < :date");
        return super.findByQuery(qbe.toString(),"date",date);
    }
```

But this generates

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date
>       at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.JdbcTimestampTypeDescriptor.unwrap(JdbcTimestampTypeDescriptor.java:24)
>       at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.TimestampTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(TimestampTypeDescriptor.java:48)
>       at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:74)
>       at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
>       at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:248)
>       at org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:52)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:627) ...

Exception.

However If I update the named query like below I don't have any exception and everything looks good.

```
        String date = DateUtils.getSQLDate(DateUtils.getToday());
        DateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date edate = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);
        StringBuffer qbe = new StringBuffer("select cpc from Companypermcache cpc");
        qbe.append(" where cpc.expire < :date");
        return super.findByQuery(qbe.toString(),"date",edate);
    }
```

However I really did not understand the difference and and the need of parsing.I have many place in my project where I am using getSQLDate(), So I am concerned whether I want to parse all those dates?
In addition to that type for edate in my table is **DATETIME**

***Why we need to parse the Date when we pass a date as  argument to named query????***

Comment: `Date date = DateUtils.getToday(); findByQuery(qbe.toString(),"date", date);`

Comment: Is it like we can only pass Date value to namedquery?

Comment: It would make sense to pass a Date, LocalDate, int, BigDecimal or whatever and not always a String. There is a conversion but it depends on what DateUilts delivers, and sometime in SQL one needs to use an SQL conversion.